# Simplify my code with Retrofit

Tags: java, android

Below I have code that I would like to simplify, but I have no idea how to do it. Each time it passes my class to load records has launched a method in this class. Question how to simplify, so I do not have as much code, because really, most is the same? The most I mean to pass all class to a single method

```
    public class WczytajUzytkownikow {
    public void wczytajPracownikow(final ZarzadzajPracownikami zarzadzajPracownikami, Integer uprawnienie) {
        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call = apiInterface.wczytajpracownikow(uprawnienie);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Uzytkownik>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Response<List<Uzytkownik>> response) {
                List<Uzytkownik> user;
                user = response.body();
                zarzadzajPracownikami.setUzytko(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Throwable t) {
                new ShowToast().showToast(zarzadzajPracownikami.getActivity(), "Brak pracowników. Dodaj pracownika");
            }
        });
    }
    public void wczytajPracownikow(final ZarzadzajKlientami zarzadzajKlientami, Integer uprawnienie) {
        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call = apiInterface.wczytajpracownikow(uprawnienie);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Uzytkownik>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Response<List<Uzytkownik>> response) {
                List<Uzytkownik> user;
                user = response.body();
                zarzadzajKlientami.setUser(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Throwable t) {
                new ShowToast().showToast(zarzadzajKlientami.getActivity(), "Brak pracowników. Dodaj pracownika");
            }
        });
    }
    public void wczytajPracownikow(final KreatorZlecenia kreatorZlecenia, Integer uprawnienie) {
        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call = apiInterface.wczytajpracownikow(uprawnienie);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Uzytkownik>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Response<List<Uzytkownik>> response) {
                List<Uzytkownik> user;
                user = response.body();

                Log.e("yyyy", "yyyy" + user.size());
                Log.e("yyyy", "yyyy" + user);

                ArrayList<Uzytkownik> uzytkownicy = new ArrayList<Uzytkownik>(user);
                kreatorZlecenia.setPracownicy(uzytkownicy);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Throwable t) {
                new ShowToast().showToast(kreatorZlecenia.getActivity(), "Brak pracowników. Dodaj pracownika");
            }
        });
    }
    public void wczytajKlientow(final KreatorZlecenia kreatorZlecenia, Integer uprawnienie){
        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call = apiInterface.wczytajpracownikow(uprawnienie);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Uzytkownik>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Response<List<Uzytkownik>> response) {
                List<Uzytkownik> list;
                list = response.body();
                ArrayList<Uzytkownik> array = new ArrayList<Uzytkownik>(list);
                kreatorZlecenia.setUzytkownicy(array);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Throwable t) {
                kreatorZlecenia.wywolajToast("Brak klientów");
                kreatorZlecenia.setUzytkownicy(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void wczytajKlientowAddDevice(final AddDevice addDevice, Integer uprawnienie){
        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call = apiInterface.wczytajpracownikow(uprawnienie);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Uzytkownik>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Response<List<Uzytkownik>> response) {
                List<Uzytkownik> list;
                list = response.body();
                ArrayList<Uzytkownik> array = new ArrayList<Uzytkownik>(list);
                addDevice.setUzytkownicy(array);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Uzytkownik>> call, Throwable t) {
                new ShowToast().showToast(addDevice.getActivity(), "Brak klientów");
            }
        });
    }

    public void wczytajPracownika(final Szczegoly szczegoly, Zlecenia zlecenia){

        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<Uzytkownik> call = apiInterface.wczytajuzytkownika(zlecenia.getIdPracownik());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Uzytkownik>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Uzytkownik> call, Response<Uzytkownik> response) {

                Uzytkownik uzytkownik = response.body();
                szczegoly.dodajWidok(szczegoly.getView(), uzytkownik);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Uzytkownik> call, Throwable t) {
                new ShowToast().showToast(szczegoly.getActivity(), "Brak klientów");
            }
        });
    }

    public void wczytajPracownika(final SzczegolyUzytkownik szczegolyUzytkownik, Sprzety sprzety){

        APIInterface apiInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
        Call<Uzytkownik> call = apiInterface.wczytajuzytkownika(sprzety.getIdUzytkownik());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Uzytkownik>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Uzytkownik> call, Response<Uzytkownik> response) {

                Uzytkownik uzytkownik = response.body();
                szczegolyUzytkownik.setUzytkownik(uzytkownik);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Uzytkownik> call, Throwable t) {
                new ShowToast().showToast(szczegolyUzytkownik.getActivity(), "Brak klientów");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you could split it in functions..

Comment: The most I mean to pass all class to a single method